# Is there an iPhone OS4 iCal API 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar, ios4

does anyone know whether iPhone OS4 contains an iCal API?

If yes, are there code samples how to use it to add events to iCal?

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not actually iCal, but you probably mean the Event Kit framework.

Check out Apple's documentation on this: [Event Kit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/EventKitFrameworkRef.pdf)

Edit: If you are a registered developer, check out the WWDC 2010 videos, Session 136 Calendar Integration with Event Kit.

Comment: iCal on Mac = Calendar on iPhone, EventKit talks to the Calendar database, so I'd say calling it the iCal API isn't far off ;)